# Spectrum of a sentence $\varphi$ with no equality sign

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, formal-languages

Assume $\varphi$ is a sentence without the equality relation. Show that if $k \in Sp(\varphi)$ and $n > k$ then $n \in Sp(\varphi)$.

$Sp(\varphi)$ is the spectrum of $\varphi$, so it is the set of all positive integers $n$ for which a finite model of $\varphi$ with $n$ elements exists.

My idea was the it doesn't matter which which relation comes up in the sentence because the only one which is the "same" in the formal language and the interpretation of the model is the equality relation. Furthermore the assignment for the variables in the sentence doesn't matter because there are no free variables. Can someone help me a hint how to formulate a proof and can tell me if I have left something out?

Comment: Well, what you wrote in the last paragraph is definitely not an answer to the question... You need to argue that if $\varphi$ is a sentence without equality that has a model of size $k$, and $n>k$, then $\varphi$ has a model of size $n$. How can you find such a model?

Comment: I would say that we can find a model in which $\varphi$ is satisfied and has $n$ elements by expanding the model we assumed to already have.

Comment: That's right. So how do you propose to expand it?

Comment: By adding elements to the universe of the model. That's probably why we had to exclude the equality sign since in the model it would be the relation $\{(m,m):m\in |\mathfrak{A} |\}$ where $|\mathfrak{A}|$ is the universe of the model. So all relations can stay the same.

Comment: Am I still on the right track?

Comment: For example the sentence $\exists x \forall y \lnot y \in x$ in the model with the universe $|\mathfrak{A}| \subset \mathbb{N}$ and the relation $\in$ is mapped to $\lt$. We could expand the universe by adding new elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sure, you can add new elements, but you also need to decide how to define the symbols in the language on the new elements to make sure you still get a model.

Comment: E.g. if your sentence is $\exists y\, \forall x\, y \leq x$, and your model is $\{0,1\}$ with $\leq = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)\}$, you can't just add new elements and keep $\leq$ the same - you won't have a model anymore.

Comment: So I have to expand the relations aswell. $\leq_{new} = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2)\}$ would be my suggestion, because $0$ for the $\exists$ and $2$ for the $\forall$, if you now what I mean.

Comment: Right, that works *in this example*. But now you have to somehow prove that there's always an expansion of the relations that works, for whatever sentence you start with.

Comment: Yes. I think understand the concept but I don't know how to tackle the proof because I have problem with the notation. Is there an easier way then to proof this directly?

Comment: An easier way than what? What do you mean by "prove this directly"? The proof is not hard, but it is necessarily abstract (since you need an argument that works for all languages and all sentences), and it requires a key insight that I don't think you've understood yet. I will write an answer with a better hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key toward solving this problem is the following construction:

Suppose $L$ is a relational language (no function or constant symbols), and $M$ is a non-empty $L$-structure. Let $a$ be an element of $M$. We define a new structure $M'$, the "blow-up" of $a$ by $n$ new elements:

- The domain of $M'$ is $M\cup \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$.
- Let $\pi\colon M'\to M$ be the function defined by $\pi(b) = b$ for $b\in M$ and $\pi(a_i) = a$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.
- For any $n$-ary relation symbol $R\in L$, and any tuple $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ from $M'$, define $(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in R^{M'}$ if and only if $(\pi(b_1),\dots,\pi(b_n))\in R^M$.

In other words, the elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are "clones" of the element $a$ in that they relate to other elements of the structure in exactly the same way $a$ does.

Now prove by induction on the complexity of the formula $\psi$, that for any  $L$-formula $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ without equality, and for any tuple $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ from $M'$, we have $M'\models \psi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ if and only if $M\models \psi(\pi(b_1),\dots,\pi(b_n))$.

It follows that if $\varphi$ is an $L$-sentence without equality, and $M\models \varphi$ with $|M| = k$, then picking any element $a\in M$, and letting $M'$ be the blow-up of $a$ by $(n-k)$ new elements, we have $M'\models \varphi$ with $|M'| = n$.